# Running Functions Synchronously in NodeJS (MongoDB Operations/Async.js)

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, asynchronous, async.js

I'm trying to do something fairly simple it seems in NodeJS - I want to run functions, one at a time. All of these functions have callbacks. I have outlined my code below, as well as the function that they run for further reference.

My problem is that the first two are working absolutely fine - one at a time, but the third iteration simply ignores the first two functions and just goes anyway. This is causing a real problem, since my program works with putting objects into a database, and it's causing duplicate objects.

The overall goal is to simply have each function run one at a time. Is there anything I'm missing here? Thanks so much for your help!

Please note that in the functions below, I have simplified all parameters to "args" for easier reading.

Calling the functions:

```
addNewProject(args);
addNewProject(args);
addNewProject(args);
```

Inside the functions, I run this:

```
function addNewProject(args) {
    var info = args;
    queue.push(function (done) {
        loopThroughDetails(info, projID, 0, function () {
            console.log('complete');
            done(null, true);
        });
    });
}
```

This calls loopThroughDetails(), which is an integration to work with async.series():

```
function loopThroughDetails(info, projID, i, callback) {
    if (i < 500) {
        getProjectDetails(projID + "-" + i, function (finished) {
            if (JSON.stringify(finished) == "[]") {
                info.ProjID = projID + "-" + i;
                DB_COLLECTION_NAME.insert(info, function (err, result) {
                    assert.equal(err, null);
                    callback();
                });
            } else {
                i++;
                loopThroughDetails(info, projID, i, callback);
            }
        });

    }
}
```

And after calling all this, I simply use async.series to accomplish the task:

```
async.series(queue, function () {
    console.log('all done');
});
```

What am I doing wrong here? Thanks so much for any help you can give! :)

Comment: is there a reason you are explicitly calling the addNewProject methods like that? Can they be called one at a time via an iterative process like a loop or... example, what if you only have one or two projects to add?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Firstly, there are many methods to achieve what you are looking for and most are subjective. I like to use an array.shift method when iterating synchronously when possible. The concept goes something like this.

```
// say you have an array of projects you need to add.
var arrayOfProjects = [{name: "project1"}, {name: "project2"}, {name: "project3"}];

// This takes the first project off of the array and assigns it to "next" leaving the remaining items on the array.

var nextProject = function (array) {

    // if there are items left then do work. Otherwise done.
    if (array.length > 0) {
        // shift the item off of the array and onto "next"
        var next = array.shift();

        addNewProject(next);

    }

} 
var addNewProject = function (project) {
    // Do stuff with the project
    console.log("project name: ", project.name);
    // When complete start over
    nextProject(arrayOfProjects);
}

// Start the process
nextProject(arrayOfProjects);
```

[Here is a working Example](https://jsfiddle.net/jherter/078q5q89/)

if you inspect the page you will see the projects logged to the console in order.

Comment: Thank you so much for all of your help! This simple explanation just made my week!! :) Had been fiddling with this for five days. Not sure why someone downvoted this perfectly good answer :(

Comment: You are welcome! Some people are just narcissistic and don't care about others. The objective here is to assist when and where you can. You may not always get the most syntactically correct answer but sometimes a simple concept can help. It seems that people expect you to be an expert already.

Comment: Agreed! I guess it doesn't matter that people are downvoting it now, since the answer's already here :)